# Why is while loop inside a for loop entering into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

While loop entering into infinite loop.

```
    for(int s=1; s<=500; s++)
    {  
        //System.out.println(i);
        int total=0;
        while(s != 0) {
            //System.out.println(s);
            int digit = s % 10;
            //System.out.println(digit+" "+s);
            total = total+(digit*digit*digit);
            //System.out.println(total);
            //reversed = reversed*10 + digit;
            s = s/10;
            //System.out.println(s);
            }
        if (total==s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

When i try to run this it enters into an infinite loop, if anyone can explain it and then the last if never gets executed. I am trying to print armstrong numbers from 1 to 500. If anyone can debug it and give me the correct code or at least help me get to know what is going on here.

Comment: `s = s/10;` ask yourself the question - what is `1/10` - remember, integer only answer

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to learn [how to use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `while` loop will not be infinite because `s/10` will return `0` (keep in mind it's all integer and in integer `1/10 = 0`).

The `for` loop however will be infinite because each time you run through the `while` loop you set `s` to `0` and then the instruction in the `for` loop increments it by 1, so `s` ends up being `1` in every iteration of the `for` loop.

As for the `if` statement, it does not execute because in your code `total = total+(digit*digit*digit);` where `digit = s % 10` that results to `1`, hence in the `if` condition you'll end up with a condition `1 == 0` that will always evaluate to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the cycle variable s: s=s/10. Use the temporary variable instead:

```
for(int s=1; s<=500; s++)
{  
    //System.out.println(i);
    int total=0; int q = s;
    while(q != 0) {
        //System.out.println(s);
        int digit = q % 10;
        //System.out.println(digit+" "+q);
        total = total+(digit*digit*digit);
        //System.out.println(total);
        //reversed = reversed*10 + digit;
        q = q/10;
        //System.out.println(s);
        }
    if (total==s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```